# Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() while using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a problem when using foreach, the error can be seen below along with the code

> A PHP Error was encountered everity: Warning

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

this is the code:

```
<tbody>
                            <?php
                                $no = 1;                                                
                                $marketSize = 0;
                                $pmarketShare = 0;
                                $cmarketShare = 0;
                                $rprevenue = 0;
                                $prevenue = 0;
                                $crevenue =0;
                                    
                                if($value['data']->num_rows() > 0): 
                                foreach ($value['data']->result() as $row):
                                    $marketSize += $row->total_size;
                                    $pmarketShare += $row->avg_share;
                                    $cmarketShare += $row->sum_share;
                                    $rprevenue =0;
                                    $prevenue =0;
                                    $crevenue =0;
                            ?>  
                            <?php endforeach; endif;?>
                        
                            <?php
                            foreach ($data as $row) :  ?>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                <tr>                               
                                    <td width="10px"><?= $no++ ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a data-market="<?= $row->kota; ?>" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= $row->kota; ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a data-market="<?= $row->total_size; ?>" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= number_format($row->total_size, 2, ',', '.') ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a data-market="<?= $row->avg_share; ?>" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= number_format($row->avg_share, 2, ',', '.'). "%" ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a data-market="<?= $row->sum_share; ?>" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= number_format($row->sum_share, 2, ',', '.') ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a data-market="0" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= number_format($rprevenue, 2, ',', '.') ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a data-market="0" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= number_format($prevenue, 2, ',', '.') ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <a data-market="0" data-tahun="<?= $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                                            <?= number_format($crevenue, 2, ',', '.') ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

I try to make the table but it only show 1 column because that error

Comment: You have two loops. Which one gives the warning? And where did you define $data? I don't see it

Comment: You got _two_ foreach loops there, so it would be helpful if you at least told us, which one the error is referring to. Your second loop has an empty body (not sure what the point of that is supposed to be) - but I am assuming, $data simply doesn't exist ...? Did you perhaps want to loop over `$value['data']->result()` a second time, after you already did it once to sum up some values?

Comment: Your two foreach() loops are messy and we can't understand what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you to early closed the loop.

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) :  ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

try change like below

```
<?php
    $no = 1;
    $marketSize = 0;
    $pmarketShare = 0;
    $cmarketShare = 0;
    $rprevenue = 0;
    $prevenue = 0;
    $crevenue = 0;
?>
    <?php if($value['data']->num_rows() > 0)  : ?>
        <?php foreach ($value['data']->result() as $row) : ?>
            <?php $marketSize += $row->total_size;
                  $pmarketShare += $row->avg_share;
                  $cmarketShare += $row->sum_share;
                  $rprevenue = 0;
                  $prevenue = 0;
                  $crevenue = 0;
            ?>  
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php foreach ($data as $row) :  ?>
        <tr>                               
            <td width="10px"><?php $no++ ?></td>
            <td>
                <a data-market="<?php $row->kota; ?>" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php $row->kota; ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a data-market="<?php $row->total_size; ?>" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php number_format($row->total_size, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a data-market="<?php $row->avg_share; ?>" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php number_format($row->avg_share, 2, ',', '.') . "%"; ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a data-market="<?php $row->sum_share; ?>" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php number_format($row->sum_share, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a data-market="0" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php number_format($rprevenue, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a data-market="0" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php number_format($prevenue, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a data-market="0" data-tahun="<?php $filter['yearstart']; ?>">
                    <?php number_format($crevenue, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
```